# pass visible frame reference to settings flyout

Tags: windows-8

In my Windows 8 App, I have a Popup which displays when clicking a link on the charm bar.  How do I pass the current applications visible frame to the the popup?  I would like to display and do different things based on where they call the charms bar and open the settings.

To create my settings popup i do the following:

```
void onCommandsRequested(SettingsPane settingsPane, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    UICommandInvokedHandler handler = new UICommandInvokedHandler(onSettingsCommand);

    SettingsCommand generalCommand = new SettingsCommand("SettingId", "Setting", handler);
    eventArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(generalCommand);

}

void onSettingsCommand(IUICommand command)
{
    // Create a SettingsFlyout the same dimenssions as the Popup.
    MyApp.Common.LayoutAwarePage mypane = new SettingsFlyout;
}
```

Comment: your question is not very clear to me?

Comment: when i saw visible frame i'm saying the current frame displayed on my tablet.  is there a way to get access to that from within the settings popup? is there something global i can reference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass current frame as `DataContext` to popup.

```
var popup = new Popup();
popup.DataContext = this;
```